# Why do I have to pass a unique pointer twice as reference to an operator overloading?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have an operator overloading of the "<<" operator that accepts two arguments as reference, one of type ostream and the other from an interface class that I have created. The problem is that I want to pass a unique pointer to an object, which its class inherits from this interface class, with a cout to this function in a for loop, like this:

```
for(std::unique_ptr<bank_account> &obj: list_of_accounts)
    cout << &objeto;
```

here's the operator overloading:

```
void operator<<(std::ostream &COUT, const bank_account_interface &obj);
```

Why do I have to pass the object in the for loop as a reference again when I try to display it with the cout? Because the overloading function already accepts the object as a reference, why do I have to do it twice?

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. Currently I see too much wording that do not make the aim clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,

```
cout << &objeto;
```

seems to be wrong, as the loop variable is called `obj`, not `objeto`.

Secondly,

```
cout << &obj;
```

would output the address of the `unique_ptr` holding the `bank_account`. You want to use

```
cout << *obj;
```

This will dereference the `unique_ptr`, yielding a `bank_account &`. Then this can be used to call the overloaded operator.